# How to properly handle a win32 GUI message loop?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm making a simple text editor win32 application for fun. I'm having a peculiar problem with my program. It seems that my program is not returning zero when it exits. Instead, it is returning 1385929. When my main GUI window is destroyed, I use `PostQuitMessage( 0 )`, but it seems that is not what is being returned in my main function's `message.wParam`. Here is my code thus far,

```
#define WIDTH 500
#define HEIGHT 400

#define EDIT_ID 10

LRESULT CALLBACK windowProc( HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    static HDC deviceContext = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    static HWND editControl = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    switch ( message )
    {
        case WM_CREATE :
            deviceContext = GetDC( window );

            if ( !deviceContext )
            {
                showWindowsError( "Creating Device Context", FALSE );
                DestroyWindow( window );
            }

            editControl = CreateWindow(
                                       "EDIT",
                                       NULL,
                                       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT |
                                       ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_NOHIDESEL,
                                       0,
                                       0,
                                       0,
                                       0,
                                       window,
                                       ( HMENU )EDIT_ID,
                                       ( HINSTANCE )GetWindowLong( window, GWL_HINSTANCE ),
                                       NULL
                                      );

            if ( !editControl )
            {
                showWindowsError( "Creating Edit Control", TRUE );
                DestroyWindow( window );
            }

            return 0;
        break;

        case WM_COMMAND :
            switch ( wParam )
            {
                case WM_UNDO :
                    SendMessage( editControl, WM_UNDO, 0, 0 );
                break;

                case WM_CUT :
                    SendMessage( editControl, WM_CUT, 0, 0 );
                break;

                case WM_COPY :
                    SendMessage( editControl, WM_COPY, 0, 0 );
                break;

                case WM_PASTE :
                    SendMessage( editControl, WM_PASTE, 0, 0 );
                break;

                case WM_CLEAR :
                    SendMessage( editControl, WM_CLEAR, 0, 0 );
                break;

                default:
                    return DefWindowProc( window, message, wParam, lParam );
            }

        case WM_SIZE :
            MoveWindow( editControl, 0, 0, LOWORD( lParam ), HIWORD( lParam ), TRUE );

            return 0;
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY :
            ReleaseDC( window, deviceContext );
            DestroyWindow( editControl );
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );

            return 0;
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc( window, message, wParam, lParam );
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR CmdArgs, int nCmdShow )
{
    WNDCLASSEX windowClass = { 0 };
    HWND window = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    MSG message = { 0 };
    HBRUSH windowColor = CreateSolidBrush( GetSysColor( COLOR_WINDOW ) );

    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof( windowClass );
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = windowProc;
    windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    windowClass.hbrBackground = windowColor;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = "TextEditorWindow";

    if ( !RegisterClassEx( &windowClass ) )
    {
        DeleteObject( windowColor );
        showWindowsError( "Registering Windows Class", TRUE );
    }

    window = CreateWindow(
                           "TextEditorWindow",
                           "Text Editor",
                           WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT,
                           WIDTH,
                           HEIGHT,
                           NULL,
                           NULL,
                           hInstance,
                           NULL
                        );

    if ( !window )
    {
        DeleteObject( windowColor );
        showWindowsError( "Creating GUI", TRUE );
    }

    ShowWindow( window, SW_SHOW );
    UpdateWindow( window );

    do
    {
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    } while ( GetMessage( &message, window, 0, 0 ) > 0 );

    DeleteObject( windowColor );
    return message.wParam;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should call GetMessage first in your loop, before TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your call to `GetMessage()` has the 2nd parameter set to your window's `HWND`, which limits the messages received only to those sent to that window - see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) of the API function.

`WM_QUIT` is, on the other hand, a message sent to the thread running the message pump, without any particular window. Because of that filter, you don't receive it and `message.wParam` is never set to that `0`.

But why does the loop end and the program shuts down anyway? Because that `HWND` in `window` gets invalid after the window is closed, therefore `GetMessage()` ends with an error and returns `-1`.

---

Additionally, you are currently calling `TranslateMessage()` and `DispatchMessage()` with `message` before it is filled with any correct data, on the first iteration. The loop should rather be like this:

```
while ( GetMessage( &message, NULL, 0, 0 ) > 0 )
{
    TranslateMessage( &message );
    DispatchMessage( &message );
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why the loop terminates anyway. You might want to point out that this (passing an invalid `HWND`) is one of the conditions, where `GetMessage` returns a value below zero. Other than that, a very solid analysis.